# jQuery/TinyMCE displaying and removing multiple textareas with animation

Tags: jquery, tinymce, textarea, hidden

On a dynamically generated page I have X TinyMCE-textarea, with jquery and css these "forms" are being hidden or displayed, based on "select". At first, TinyMCE displayed without problem, but after I select something (another language, select-option), and jquery hide all of them, and when the selected div is displayed, TinyMCE is initialized without buttons. I tried to turn off TinyMCE before .hide(), than turn on after .show(), but something is wrong. Sorry for my English, and thank you for help.
HTML

```
<select id="langs">
      <option name="0">Magyar</option>
      <option name="1">Angol</option>   
</select>
<form id="addarticleform" method="post" action="" >
    <input type="submit" value="Mentés" name="addarticlesubmit"/>
    <div id="form_0">
        <p>Cikk címe: <input type="text" name="articletitle_0" value="" /></p>
        Cikk tartalma:
        <textarea name="articletext_0"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div id="form_1">
        <p>Cikk címe: <input type="text" name="articletitle_1" value="" /></p>
        Cikk tartalma:
        <textarea name="articletext_1"></textarea>
    </div>
</form>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){        
    $('#langs').change(function() {
        //Remove tinymce
        removeTinyMCE();
        $('#addarticleform div').hide('slow');
        var e = '#form_' + $(':selected', $(this)).attr('name');
        $(e).show('slow');
        //add tinymce
        addTinyMCE();
    });
});
function removeTinyMCE () {
    alert("removing");
    tinyMCE.execCommand('mceRemoveControl', false, $("#container textarea"));
    //tinyMCE.execCommand('mceRemoveControl', false, $("#container textarea").attr(id));
}
function addTinyMCE() {
    alert("adding");
    tinyMCE.execCommand('mceAddControl', false, $("#container textarea"));
}
```

UPDATE:
My solution:

```
initTinyMCE("textarea");
$(document).ready(function(){        
    $('#langs').change(function() {
        var tid = '#textarea_' + $(':selected', $(this)).attr('name');
        $(tid).tinymce().remove();
        $('#addarticleform div').hide('slow');
        var e = '#forms_' + $(':selected', $(this)).attr('name');
        $(e).show('slow');
        initTinyMCE(tid);
    });
});
function initTinyMCE(selector) {
    $(selector).tinymce({
        .....
    });
};
```

Comment: Why do you need to remove the control? Would using the hide method work instead? One problem is that the third parameter to the tinyMCE.execCommand() call in removeTinyMCE() is the same no matter what option is selected in the droplist. Try adding an id attribute to each textarea, and then in removeTinyMCE() anda addTinyMCE() use those id values as the parameter values.

Comment: I have to disable tinymce before the animation, than enable (because tinymce gonna be messed up after the .show()), I just dont know how. I found this removecontrol command, but dont know how it works.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to your problem might be to use `$("#container textarea").attr('id')`

instead of `$("#container textarea")` in your functions removeTinyMCE and addTinyMCE.